# Cadence: use voltage as a parameter to change resistance

Tags: gain, cadence, inverting-amplifier, behavioral-source

I designed a circuit that takes two user inputs ("vl" and "vh") and set a resistor value ((vh-vl)*100kOhm) that sets the gain of a inverting opamp amplifier. I am using Cadence and both vl and vh are configured as pPar() in the CDF editor.

**I want to turn both vh and vl into pins in the symbol view**, so instead of having the user input vl and vh in the symbol properties, the user can simply hook the two ports to two dc voltage sources. **How can I do that?**

This is a behavioral model, hence the resistance being set as a function of vh and vl.

Comment: That's all very interesting, but what is your question? Welcome to EE.SE. (Put the details in your question - not in the comments.)

Comment: I have edited my post for clarity.

Comment: Coupling a voltage to a component property is not something you can do with a schematic based model as far as I know. Your best bet is to learn how to use of and write your own **VerilogA** models. There's an example library in the Cadence installation directory. Learn that and you will be able to model almost anything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a voltage controlled resistor (VCRES from the analogLib on Cadence) and tying the positive node to vh and the negative terminal to vl. I then input 100k as the volt/res conversion factor and voi-la! Everything worked.
[image]